# Как вставить карту OSM (QML) в MainWindow?

Tags: qt, openstreetmap

Пытаюсь создать простое окно с картой. Как мне добавить карту (земли) внутрь виджета QMainWindow?
Пытаюсь простой QML объект добавить, все получается:

```
QQmlEngine *engine = new QQmlEngine(this);
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget(engine, this);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc://src/qml/test_item.qml"));
this->setCentralWidget(view);
```

test_item.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle
{
    width: 100
    height: 62
    color: "red"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

Но если я пытаюсь добавить map.qml:

```
Window {
width: parent //Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
height: parent //Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
visible: true

Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm"
}

Map {
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(55.012902, 82.950326) // Sibsutis
    zoomLevel: 14
}
}
```

Все тут же крашится...
p.s. сама карта как отдельный объект (не внутри виджета) работает прекрасно.

Comment: Может потому, что QML-объект Window создает окно верхнего уровня, а ты его пытаешься поместить в view?

Comment: @e.n.shirokov Вероятно, я только начинаю играть в QT. Подскажете как исправить?

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит при краше? Попробуйте заменить Window на Item

Comment: Да, только что почитал про иерархии, поменял на Item. Все заработало. Спасибо.